# OS X Timer with counting money app

Tags: macos, software-recommendation

I'm looking for timer that also count money. My work is paid hourly, so I want to see how much I get. It's give me energy to work a bit more.

It's like regular timer but with money earned number in the next line.

I've seen it in "On the job" app, but it looks abandoned and I do not need invoicing.

Like this one: http://www.online-stopwatch.com/cash-clock/

Answer (score 1):

The best "free"solution I found is the Cash Clock, allowing you to set the $ amount per hour or minute or second.

I was slightly on the high earnings site just to show the effect, but if you do make $3600 per hour let me know what job is it.

[image: money clock]

You can download it from [here](http://www.online-stopwatch.com/download-stopwatch/) to run it offline, or just let it run in they web site.

> www.online-stopwatch.com is letting you download our cool stopwatch
>   and countdown timers for free!
>
> This will let you use the stopwatch when you are not on the internet.
>   You may have to download a new version from time to time though, as
>   updates and tweaks are made.
>
> These files do not need installing! They will just run from anywhere
>   on your PC. AND they will all work full screen.

Requirements:

All of our stopwatches/countdowns require Adobe Flash Player to work on your desktop.

http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/updaters/15/flashplayer_15_sa.dmg

The code is:

```
<param name="movie" value="http://www.online-stopwatch.com/swf/cash-clock.swf"><param name="quality" value="high"><param name="menu" value="true"><embed width="400" height="220" src="http://www.online-stopwatch.com/swf/cash-clock.swf" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"></embed> <br> <b><font size='2' color='#000000'>Get a Stopwatch like this or make your own! At: <a title="Online Stopwatch" href="http://www.online-stopwatch.com">Online Stopwatch</a></font></b>
```